# error spc0212: Cannot update readonly Business Component Category. (Genexus)

Tags: variáveis, genexus

Este erro aparece se referenciando a uma variável quando a chamo com `&Exemplo.Load()` e `&Exemplo.Insert()`.

> error spc0212: Cannot update readonly Business Component Category.
> Category é uma transação

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a transação "Category" tem a propriedade "update policy" em "Readonly" por este motivo, não se pode adicionar registros (`insert`).
Informações Adicionais: [[1]](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6774,Specification%20Codes%20from%20spc0150%20onwards), [[2]](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?29599,Update%20Policy%20property)